# python display image using Image

Tags: python, image, display

I wrote this short code to capture a picture with a camera. Its working fine - I have problems showing (& later closing) the image I just did. I am using `newest = max(glob.iglob('*.jpg'), key=os.path.getctime)` to locate the image I just did - now I want to open and show the image which doesnt work `im = Image.open(newest)` `im.show()`-  any suggestions?

```
import Image
import picamera
import time
import sys
import datetime
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import glob
import os

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(16, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(18, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
now = datetime.datetime.now()
camera = picamera.PiCamera()
camera.resolution = (1920, 1080)
camera.framerate = 24
camera.start_preview()
while True:
        input_state=GPIO.input(16)
        input_state2=GPIO.input(18)
        if input_state == False:
                        zahlen = [4,3,2,1,0]
                        for i in zahlen:
                                camera.annotate_text = '' + str(i+1)
                                n = i+1
                                print n
                                time.sleep(1)
                        camera.annotate_text = ''
                        camera.capture('Hausmesse_' + str(now.hour) + ':' + str(now.minute) + ':' + str(now.second) + '.jpg')
                        newest = max(glob.iglob('*.jpg'), key=os.path.getctime)
                        im = Image.open(newest)
                        im.show()
                        time.sleep(5)

        if input_state2 == False:
                #time.sleep(5)
                sys.exit()
```

EDIT:

I tried using `matplotlib` - it gives me data for the image `image=mplImage.imread(newest)` but doesnt show it using the command `plt.imshow(image)`

```
[[[125 106 128]
  [123 106 125]
  [117 103 120]
  ...,
  [157 133 147]
  [155 131 145]
  [154 130 144]]

 [[129 110 132]
  [126 109 128]
  [116 103 120]
  ...,
  [154 130 144]
  [154 130 144]
  [159 135 149]]

 [[127 109 131]
  [124 109 130]
  [118 105 123]
  ...,
  [157 133 146]
  [155 129 145]
  [155 131 145]]

 ...,
 [[130 129 134]
  [127 126 131]
  [124 122 125]
  ...,
  [211 206 203]
  [210 205 202]
  [209 204 201]]

 [[128 126 131]
  [126 124 129]
  [133 128 134]
  ...,
  [209 203 203]
  [209 203 203]
  [212 206 206]]

 [[135 133 138]
  [130 128 133]
  [129 124 130]
  ...,
  [210 204 204]
  [210 204 204]
  [212 206 206]]]
```

Comment: Any error message ?

Comment: @Matei sadly none, it just "skips" the part

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too experienced using Image, however I would point you to MatPlotLib. (see http://matplotlib.org/users/image_tutorial.html).

A quick example is where you have your image as an array (or even a stored file) you can just:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mplImage

# If image is not already an array then:
image=mplImage.imread('testimage.png')

plt.imshow(image)
```